# Tumblr blog, images are overlapping with Infinite Scroll with Masonry

Tags: jquery, html, css, infinite-scroll, masonry

i have a Tumblr blog on which i have installed Masonry and Infinite Scroll. I have problem: when i scroll down the page, some images load overlapped one on each other.

This is the code i am using at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/rSGl20lfv/masonry.js">
</script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/df28qmy/SHUlh3i7s/jquery.infinitescroll.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/lLwkowcqm/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(window).load(function () {
$('.posts').masonry(),
$('.masonryWrap').infinitescroll({
navSelector : "div#navigation",
// selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "div#navigation a#nextPage",
// selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : ".entry",
// selector for all items you'll retrieve
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 11000,
loadingImg : "",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
},
```

// call masonry as a callback.

```
function() { $('.posts').masonry({ appendedContent: $(this) }); }
);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(window).load(function(){$("p").remove(":contains('Source:')");});</script>
```

Please i need help, this is the link of the blog so you can see the problem, just scroll down   http://allaricercadeltempoperduto.tumblr.com/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, transition is a little slow though

Comment: if i scroll down to the end, the images are overlapped, but if i do this thing one time and then i refresh the page, no more images overlapped...